# Obtain certain text from Python String after every colon

Tags: python, string, list

I have a python string  a = "Name:john  KES:50  code:5234", how can I go through the string (a) to get the list output b = ["john", 50, 5234], keeping the order ie.

Comment: we can do this with regex expressions if all expressions are of that from.use re.findall()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
a = "Name:john KES:50 code:5234"
a = a.split(" ")
ls=[]
for i in a:
    c = i.split(':')[1]
    if c.isdigit():
        c = int(c)
        ls.append(c)
    else:
        ls.append(c)
ls
```